# Sorting a list of time string ranges in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have total 9 elements in string array.

```
strArr = [ "1 days ago","10 hours ago","2 hours ago","3 days ago","3 hours ago","4 hours ago",
"5 hours ago","6 hours ago","7 hours ago"]
```

I need to sort  array like this

```
sortedArr = ["2 hours ago","3 hours ago","4 hours ago","5 hours ago",
"6 hours ago","7 hours ago","10 hours ago", "1 days ago","3 days ago"]
```

Comment: That would be pretty hard, especially w.r.t. localization. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: @Alexander : we are getting this data from API based on that we created the unique keys array as above.

Comment: You should not be working with strings. You should be working with timestamps. Those are easy to sort (or filter or anything else). Never work with such strings except for displaying a relative timestamp to the user.

Comment: Are you sure about not getting "25 hour ago" or "1 day and 1 hour ago" or "just now" or anything else that not using `<count> <unit> ago` pattern?

Comment: NLP can handle it like a charm but it's out of the scope of your question a bit.

Comment: Is this the only way you can get data from the API? You'd have a much easier time if you could get timestamps and then format them yourself as needed after sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your collection of strings are consistent you can just pass a custom sort predicate. If the previous element has the hours suffix and the next element doesn't just return true otherwise return the  `localizedStandardCompare` result

```
let strings = [ "1 days ago","10 hours ago","2 hours ago","3 days ago","3 hours ago","4 hours ago",
"5 hours ago","6 hours ago","7 hours ago"]

let sorted = strings.sorted{ $0.hasSuffix(" hours ago") && !$1.hasSuffix(" hours ago") ? true : $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending  }
print(sorted) // ["2 hours ago", "3 hours ago", "4 hours ago", "5 hours ago", "6 hours ago", "7 hours ago", "10 hours ago", "1 days ago", "3 days ago"]
```

Comment: Cool, basically the same logic I used in my answer but with a small fraction of the code I needed. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it 3 steps:

> 1. create a model value to represent a sentence
> 2. make the model value comparable
> 3. transform each sentence into a model value
> 4. sort the model values
> 5. transform each model value into a sentence again

### Step 1: create a model value to represent a sentence

An enum is a good way of representing your general sentence

```
enum TimePoint {

    case hours(Int)
    case days(Int)

    init?(sentence: String) {
        let tokens = sentence.split(separator: " ")
        guard
            tokens.count == 3,
            let firstToken = tokens.first,
            let value = Int(firstToken)
            else { return nil }

        let unitString = String(tokens[1])

        switch unitString {
        case "hours": self = .hours(value)
        case "days": self = .days(value)
        default: return nil
        }

    }

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .days(let value): return "\(value) days ago"
        case .hours(let value): return "\(value) hours ago"
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 2: make the model value Comparable

```
extension TimePoint: Comparable {

    private var hours: Int {
        switch self {
        case .hours(let value): return value
        case .days(let value): return 24 * value
        }
    }

    static func < (lhs: TimePoint, rhs: TimePoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hours < rhs.hours
    }
}
```

### Steps 3, 4 and 5 (transform to model, sort and transform again to text)

Given this input array

```
let sentences = ["1 days ago","10 hours ago","2 hours ago","3 days ago","3 hours ago","4 hours ago", "5 hours ago","6 hours ago","7 hours ago"]
```

You can now write

```
let sortedSentences = sentences
    .compactMap(TimePoint.init)
    .sorted()
    .map { $0.description }
```

That's it

```
["2 hours ago", "3 hours ago", "4 hours ago", "5 hours ago", "6 hours ago", "7 hours ago", "10 hours ago", "1 days ago", "3 days ago"]
```

Comment: While this works, it's solving the wrong problem. This approach really doesn't scale (across multiple different phrase types and different languages). I would only recommend this as a last resort, if it's immpossible to obtain saner input data.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, yeah that’s right. My solution is tailored on the kind of dataset provided with the question. I don’t have a more general solution unfortunately.